# Fail to run the example of 3D Surface Mesh Generation with CGAL

Tags: c++, g++, macos-sierra, cgal, linker-errors

I am trying to run [this example](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesher/index.html#Chapter_3D_Surface_Mesh_Generation) of 3D Surface Mesh Generation with CGAL. The code is:

```
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh_default_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Complex_2_in_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/make_surface_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/Implicit_surface_3.h>
// default triangulation for Surface_mesher
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh_default_triangulation_3 Tr;
// c2t3
typedef CGAL::Complex_2_in_triangulation_3<Tr> C2t3;
typedef Tr::Geom_traits GT;
typedef GT::Sphere_3 Sphere_3;
typedef GT::Point_3 Point_3;
typedef GT::FT FT;
typedef FT (*Function)(Point_3);
typedef CGAL::Implicit_surface_3<GT, Function> Surface_3;

FT sphere_function (Point_3 p) {
    const FT x2=p.x()*p.x(), y2=p.y()*p.y(), z2=p.z()*p.z();
    return x2+y2+z2-1;
}

int main() {
    Tr tr;            // 3D-Delaunay triangulation
    C2t3 c2t3 (tr);   // 2D-complex in 3D-Delaunay triangulation
    // defining the surface
    Surface_3 surface(sphere_function,             // pointer to function
                      Sphere_3(CGAL::ORIGIN, 2.)); // bounding sphere
    // Note that "2." above is the *squared* radius of the bounding sphere!
    // defining meshing criteria
    CGAL::Surface_mesh_default_criteria_3<Tr> criteria(30.,  // angular bound
                                                       0.1,  // radius bound
                                                       0.1); // distance bound
    // meshing surface
    CGAL::make_surface_mesh(c2t3, surface, criteria, CGAL::Non_manifold_tag());
    std::cout << "Final number of points: " << tr.number_of_vertices() << "\n";
}
```

The `CMakeLists` file contains:

```
# Created by the script cgal_create_CMakeLists
# This is the CMake script for compiling a set of CGAL applications.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(_cgal)

# CGAL and its components
find_package( CGAL QUIET COMPONENTS Core )

if ( NOT CGAL_FOUND )

  message(STATUS "This project requires the CGAL library, and will not be compiled.")
  return()  

endif()

# include helper file
include( ${CGAL_USE_FILE} )


# Boost and its components
find_package( Boost REQUIRED )

if ( NOT Boost_FOUND )

  message(STATUS "This project requires the Boost library, and will not be compiled.")

  return()  

endif()


# Creating entries for target: out
# ############################
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(_cgal ${SOURCE_FILES})

add_to_cached_list( CGAL_EXECUTABLE_TARGETS _cgal )

# Link the executable to CGAL and third-party libraries
target_link_libraries(_cgal   ${CGAL_LIBRARIES} ${CGAL_3RD_PARTY_LIBRARIES} )
```

Output of `cmake`:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.1.0
-- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot
-- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot - yes
-- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
-- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/gcc-7
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/gcc-7 -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot
-- Checking whether CXX compiler has -isysroot - yes
-- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
-- Checking whether CXX compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/bin/g++-7
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/bin/g++-7 -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Build type: Release
-- USING CXXFLAGS = ' -DNDEBUG'
-- USING EXEFLAGS = ' '
-- Targetting Unix Makefiles
-- Using /usr/local/bin/g++-7 compiler.
-- DARWIN_VERSION=16
-- Mac Leopard detected
-- Requested component: Core
-- Requested component: MPFR
-- Requested component: GMP
-- Boost version: 1.64.0
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target _cgal
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_cgal.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable _cgal
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "CGAL::get_mode(std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& CGAL::insert<CGAL::Epick>(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick> const&, CGAL::Cartesian_tag const&) in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [_cgal] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/_cgal.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/_cgal.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [_cgal] Error 2
```

I would highly appreciate if you could explain me how to fix it.

**UPD:** [This](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues/2116) seems to be related, but do not get what packages I should add in my cmake.

**UPD2:** [I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637164/c-linking-error-after-upgrading-to-mac-os-x-10-9-xcode-5-0-1) that it may be related to the issue of:

> There are two implementations of the standard C++ library available on
>   OS X: libstdc++ and libc++. They are not binary compatible and libMLi3
>   requires libstdc++.
>
> On 10.8 and earlier libstdc++ is chosen by default, on 10.9 libc++ is
>   chosen by default. To ensure compatibility with libMLi3, we need to
>   choose libstdc++ manually.
>
> To do this, add -stdlib=libstdc++ to the linking command.

I modified the following line in the CMake file, but it did not help:

```
# Link the executable to CGAL and third-party libraries
target_link_libraries(_cgal ${CGAL_LIBRARIES} ${CGAL_3RD_PARTY_LIBRARIES}  -static-libstdc++)
```

**UPD3:** I tried the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619569/cgal-linking-error-on-mac-os-x), however it does not help

```
project( _cgal )

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.10)

find_package(CGAL QUIET COMPONENTS Core )

if ( CGAL_FOUND )

  include( ${CGAL_USE_FILE} )

  include( CGAL_CreateSingleSourceCGALProgram )

  create_single_source_cgal_program( "main.cpp" )

else()

    message(STATUS "This program requires the CGAL library, and will not be compiled.")

endif()
```

Comment: I tried on my machine and it is working. Maybe the header of CGAL and the library you are using are not coming from the same release?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just tried to reinstall CGAL with brew... What else should I try?

Comment: @sloriot, could you please take a look one more time? I updated the question with the steps that I tried. I do not code in C++ a lot, so maybe I miss something basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: fix compiler! CGAL was installed with `brew` that uses `clang` compiler. But to compile the project I had been using `g++`. I should code in C++ more often :)